# How to resolve an encoding issue?

Tags: python, excel, csv, encoding

I need to read the content of a csv file using Python. However when I run this code:

```
with(open(self.path, 'r')) as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, dialect=csv.excel, delimiter=';')
    self.data = [[cell for cell in row] for row in csv_reader]
```

I get this error:

```
File "C:\Python36\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 1137: character maps to <undefined>
```

My understanding is that this file was not encoded in cp-1252, and that I need to find out what encoding was used. I tried a bunch of things, but nothing worked for now.

**About the file:**

- It is sent by an external company, I can't have more information about it.
- It comes with other similar files, with which I don't have any issue when I run the same code
- It has an .xls extension, but is more a csv file delimited with semicolons
- When I open it with Excel it opens in Compatibility mode. But I don't see any sort of encoding issue: everything displays right.

**What I already tried:**

- Saving it under a different file format to get rid of the compatibility mode
- Adding an encoding in the first line of my code: (I tried more or less randomly some encodings that I know of)

  with(open(self.path, 'r', encoding = 'utf8')) as csv_file:
- Copy-pasting the content of the file into a new file, or deleting the whole content of the file. Still does not work. This one really bugs me because I feel like it means the probelm is not in the content of the file, and not in the file itself.
- Searching a lot everywhere how to solve this kind of issue.

Comment: You could try reading the file using `pandas` or `openpyxl`.

Comment: Python 2 or Python 3? (May be relevant).

Comment: If it opens right in Excel, try saving from Excel to another CSV file. This might resolve the encoding issues without you having to find out exactly what was wrong. Or it might not ...

Comment: Python 3.
I actually tried this before seeing your comment, and it worked (as I explained in another answer). Thanks anyway !

Comment: try [chardet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) to detect encoding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found some sort of solution :

1. Open the file with Excel
2. Display the file properly using the "Text to Columns" feature
3. Save the file to csv format
4. Run the code

This does not quite satisfy me, but it works.
I still don't understand what the problem actually is, and why this solved it, so I am interested in any additional information !

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using pandas library (as well as numpy), it is very handy when it comes to data manipulation. This function imports the data from an xlsx or csv file type.

/!\ change `datapath` according to your needs /!\

```
import os
import pandas as pd

def GetData(directory, dataUse, format):
    dataPath = os.getcwd() + "\\Data\\" + directory + "\\" + dataUse + "Set." + format
    if format == "xlsx":
        dataSet = pd.read_excel(dataPath, sheetname = 'Sheet1')
    elif format == "csv":
        dataSet = pd.read_csv(dataPath)
    return dataSet
```

Comment: It does not solve the issue. I get the error message :
`  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 535, in pandas.parser.TextReader.__cinit__ (pandas\parser.c:6086)
  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 740, in pandas.parser.TextReader._get_header (pandas\parser.c:9266)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: invalid continuation byte`

Comment: No I don't... I have been trying to find out but I did not succeed,

Comment: Open your file with notepad. Then, go to `save as`; there will be an option for selecting your encoding.

Comment: The one selected is the one your file was encoded with.

Comment: Maybe try to create a new excel file, in the data tab > Get External Data > From Other Sources > From XML data import > (select all files type) chose your file. Wait for your import to end and save as excel file.

Comment: When I open with anything else than Excel, the encoding is not right. I am gessing the XML thing should work, as I already found a similar solution. Thanks !